# What is file position pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, file-handling

I am learning C using [this](http://thecguru.com/character-io-file-handling-in-c/) site.

Under `fgetc()` Function the author said:

> This function reads a single character from a file and after reading increments the file position pointer.

```
FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

What I want to ask is that the `file position pointer` is different from the pointer `fp` or not?

Comment: There is a difference between pointing to a file and pointing to a position in a file.

Comment: @JohnColeman so both are different

Comment: Yes. You need to keep `fp` pointing to the file itself while the position pointer advances through the file. Otherwise -- how are you going to close it when you are done?

Comment: Compare a pointer to a string and having an *index* pointing to a character inside that string.

Comment: The pointer "`FILE* fp`" is a pointer in the sense of the C language's pointer variables. The "*file position pointer*" is a pointer in the sense of the indexing-pattern: It refers/points/marks/identifies to a specific index/position in a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they are not the same. `fp` is a pointer to a structure `FILE`. The file position pointer points to the position in the file, obviously.

You can find this by looking at `stdio.h` in your include path. In FreeBSD, FILE is defined as:

```
struct __sFILE {
    unsigned char *_p;  /* (*) current position in (some) buffer */
    int _r;     /* (*) read space left for getc() */
    int _w;     /* (*) write space left for putc() */
    short   _flags;     /* (*) flags, below; this FILE is free if 0 */
    short   _file;      /* (*) fileno, if Unix descriptor, else -1 */
    struct  __sbuf _bf; /* (*) the buffer (at least 1 byte, if !NULL) */
    int _lbfsize;   /* (*) 0 or -_bf._size, for inline putc */
/* operations */
void    *_cookie;   /* (*) cookie passed to io functions */
int (*_close)(void *);
int (*_read)(void *, char *, int);
fpos_t  (*_seek)(void *, fpos_t, int);
int (*_write)(void *, const char *, int);

/* separate buffer for long sequences of ungetc() */
struct  __sbuf _ub; /* ungetc buffer */
unsigned char   *_up;   /* saved _p when _p is doing ungetc data */
int _ur;        /* saved _r when _r is counting ungetc data */

/* tricks to meet minimum requirements even when malloc() fails */
unsigned char _ubuf[3]; /* guarantee an ungetc() buffer */
unsigned char _nbuf[1]; /* guarantee a getc() buffer */

/* separate buffer for fgetln() when line crosses buffer boundary */
struct  __sbuf _lb; /* buffer for fgetln() */

/* Unix stdio files get aligned to block boundaries on fseek() */
int _blksize;   /* stat.st_blksize (may be != _bf._size) */
fpos_t  _offset;    /* current lseek offset */

struct pthread_mutex *_fl_mutex;    /* used for MT-safety */
struct pthread *_fl_owner;  /* current owner */
int _fl_count;  /* recursive lock count */
int _orientation;   /* orientation for fwide() */
__mbstate_t _mbstate;   /* multibyte conversion state */
int _flags2;    /* additional flags */
};
typedef struct __sFILE FILE;
```

Comment: Can you point me which member of FILE structure indicate file position pointer ?

Comment: is that *curp ?

Comment: @Cody I found that on a site somewhere. I'm trying to find it in my stdio.h but keep getting interrupted. It depends on the OS I believe. On FreeBSD, it's quite different from that. EDIT: I edited my answer to show FreeBSD's definition.

Comment: @alk Yeah, fixed.

Comment: This `fpos_t  _offset;` member probably represents the "*file position pointer*".

Comment: is this struct same for different imlementations?

Comment: @Nick: probably not.

Answer (score 5):

It means your current offset in the file. It is the return value of `ftell`.